# ListActivity showing white screen

Tags: android

Hi I try to make a simple listActivity with this code following Android documentation:

```
public class AddProductChoices extends ListActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product_choices);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addProductChoices));
    setListAdapter(adapter);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Option Selected " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
}
```

R.layout.add_product_choices:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="es.infofly.apps.gestcomprasnav.activities.AddProductChoices">

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Strings.xml:

```
<resources>
  <array name="addProductChoices">
    <item>Opcion 1</item>
    <item>Opcion 2</item>
    <item>Opcion 3</item>
    <item>Opcion 4</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

but all I got is a white screen. 
I tried using an array directly as a test instead getting of the strings,xml with the same result.
Can anyone tell me what I missing? Thanks

Comment: Follow this example https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/listactivity/android-listactivity-example/

Comment: I tried and the same, but I found when it fails. I add a response to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was becuase in the manifest.xml I call the theme of the activity to show as a dialog:

```
<activity
      android:name=".activities.AddProductChoices"
      android:label="@string/add_product_choices"
      android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" />
```

If i try using dialog theme show the white screen if I use usual size (theme, all the screen) goes well. So I use a regular AppCompatActivity and use a ListView normally:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product_choices);

    ListView choices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_choices);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.addProductChoices));
    choices.setAdapter(adapter);

    choices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent resultChoice = new Intent();
            resultChoice.putExtra("choice", position);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultChoice);
            finish();
        }
    });
```